# Parse string (node js ) .Find array of numbers into string

Tags: node.js

```
\n54766392632990,178.32.243.13,wfsdsfsdfs23432,\n54766393632990,178.32.243.13,
```

Above u can see example of string which I want to parse.. I want to get array if numbers which exist between (\n`....`,178.32.243.13) .. In this example it will be smth like :

`[54766392632990,54766393632990]` - how to make it

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"\n54766392632990,178.32.243.13,wfsdsfsdfs23432,\n54766393632990,178.32.243.13,"
.split("\n")
.filter((n)=> n!== "")
 .map(n=> parseInt(n.split(",")[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please run this script it full file your requirement

```
var ss = "\n54766392632990,178.32.243.13,wfsdsfsdfs23432,\n54766393632990,178.32.243.13,"

var ddd = ss.split(",")
console.log(ddd)
var dfd = []
ddd.forEach(function(res){
if(res.startsWith("\n"))
{
    dfd.push(res.replace("\n",""))
}
})
console.log(dfd)
```

> Result [ '54766392632990', '54766393632990' ]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to parse this string

```
let s = "\n54766392632990,178.32.243.13,wfsdsfsdfs23432,\n54766393632990,178.32.243.13,"
s = s.split("\n");
let array = [];
for(let i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
  let v = s[i].split(",178.32.243.13,");
  for(let j=0;j<v.length;j++) {
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(v[j]))) {
      array.push(v[j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(array);
```